# How to have chef template have a "["?

Tags: templates, chef-infra

I want to have chef template to generate a Django settings.py file. But looks like the list object inside of settings.py always gets chef into trouble:

This is the source code of template:

```
 91: # DNS configurations
 92: DEFAULT_NAMESERVERS = [ 
 93: <% @nameservers.each do |ns| %>
 94: '<%=#{ns}%>',
 95: <% end %>
 96: ] 
 97:
```

I always get the following error message:

```
 * template[/var/www/pdnsrestserver/pdnsrestserver/settings.py] action create

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/var/www/pdnsrestserver/pdnsrestserver/settings.py]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
    ------------------------------------
    **(erubis):96: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')'**
     _buf << '] 
               ^
    (erubis):172: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think you're missing space and having an interpolation code outside a quoted string

I think this would work:

```
 91: # DNS configurations
 92: DEFAULT_NAMESERVERS = [ 
 93: <% @nameservers.each do |ns| %>
 94: '<%= ns %>',
 95: <% end %>
 96: ] 
 97:
```

Untested code